# Mapping arrow keys when running tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

These key mappings stop working in tmux. In my `.vimrc`, I have:

```
nmap <Space> i
map <C-Down> <C-w>j
map <C-Up> <C-w>k
map <C-Left> <C-w>h
map <C-Right> <C-w>l
```

When I run `:map`, I see:

```
   <C-Right>     <C-W>l
   <C-Left>      <C-W>h
   <C-Up>        <C-W>k
   <C-Down>      <C-W>j
```

Yet when I hit control and an arrow key at the same time, it behaves as if no keybinding was set.

Comment: It's possible your OS or terminal are intercepting those key sequences.  My Vim doesn't seem to receive them with my current KiTTY/tmux setup, but I haven't looked into it too much.

Comment: Do these mappings work outside of tmux? What is your `$TERM` in tmux?

Comment: Yes, the mappings work outside tmux. `$TERM` in tmux is the same as out of `tmux`, which is `xterm-256color`.

Comment: This is a *very* involved problem you're encountering. If you'd like, I can bore you to death with the current state of this issue. I raised this issue with Micah Cowan (I think he was already aware) in 2007, and I think he's been working on it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Vim knows that *xterm*-like terminals (identified by TERM starting with `xterm`, or a particular response to the `t_RV` sequence, if it is defined) support extended sequences for certain modified keys, but it does not assume this for `screen` TERMs (which you should be using under *tmux*).

You can, however tell Vim about these sequences and enable them if TMUX is present, and TERM starts with `screen` (the first lines enable (better) mouse support under *tmux*, which you might also like):

```
if &term =~ '^screen' && exists('$TMUX')
    set mouse+=a
    " tmux knows the extended mouse mode
    set ttymouse=xterm2
    " tmux will send xterm-style keys when xterm-keys is on
    execute "set <xUp>=\e[1;*A"
    execute "set <xDown>=\e[1;*B"
    execute "set <xRight>=\e[1;*C"
    execute "set <xLeft>=\e[1;*D"
    execute "set <xHome>=\e[1;*H"
    execute "set <xEnd>=\e[1;*F"
    execute "set <Insert>=\e[2;*~"
    execute "set <Delete>=\e[3;*~"
    execute "set <PageUp>=\e[5;*~"
    execute "set <PageDown>=\e[6;*~"
    execute "set <xF1>=\e[1;*P"
    execute "set <xF2>=\e[1;*Q"
    execute "set <xF3>=\e[1;*R"
    execute "set <xF4>=\e[1;*S"
    execute "set <F5>=\e[15;*~"
    execute "set <F6>=\e[17;*~"
    execute "set <F7>=\e[18;*~"
    execute "set <F8>=\e[19;*~"
    execute "set <F9>=\e[20;*~"
    execute "set <F10>=\e[21;*~"
    execute "set <F11>=\e[23;*~"
    execute "set <F12>=\e[24;*~"
endif
```

As the comment indicates, you also need to have the window’s `xterm-keys` option enabled. You can do this for all your windows like this (in your `~/.tmux.conf`):

```
set-option -gw xterm-keys on
```

(Remember that changes to `~/.tmux.conf` are not automatically loaded. To be effective, you will need to run this command manually (in a `tmux` shell command, or at a Prefix `:` prompt), or re-load your configuration file with `source ~/.tmux.conf` (in a `tmux` shell command, or at a Prefix `:` prompt), or restart your server (exit all your sessions and restart *tmux*)).